# Managing multiple animation files in a Unity project

Tags: unity, animation, fbx, rigging, asset-workflow

I am on my project, but find it hard to understand what I'm missing from those few animation and rigging tutorials.

I have an FBX I modelled and rigged from blender... Or I could just take a model from Mixamo or other resources.

Is it possible to have loosely coupled .anim files which could be mix-matched at runtime with different FBXs?

It seems the Animator Controller can reference each .anim file independently if necessary, so I guess we can make one animation per fbx and split anim files in Unity project explorer... There must be a better way, right?

Comment: It sounds like you have an idea for how you could work with your animation assets. When you try putting this idea into practice, does anything go wrong? Do you observe a specific problem that we can help you solve, or a specific pain point in your workflow that we can help you improve? Note that we can't tell you what software to use to animate — reasonable developers can have very different opinions on that — but we can suggest ways to overcome specific issues you've found with whatever tools you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to assign the same AnimationController with the same animations to two different models. However, it can be problematic if the rigs of the two models differ. Either make sure that both models have a rig with identical hierarchy and identically named bones, or use [avatars](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfiguringtheAvatar.html) which translate the bone names between the two models.

For more information, check out the article in the Unity documentation about [animation retargeting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Retargeting.html).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about retargeting, thanks. I am also considering rigging natively within Unity: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/intro-to-unity-rigs#6032c719edbc2a33c190912c if it will streamline the process. Too early to tell. I hope we one day see tutorials about the different approaches one may take to make this work faster as a solo dev.